# Number of S3 requests generated by Redshift's UNLOAD Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

When unloading data from Redshift to S3 with PARALLEL ON, results of the select statement are split across a set of files as described in the Redshift Documentation. How does this translate into number of requests sent to S3 endpoint ?

Ex - If the UNLOAD query ( with PARALLEL ON ) generated 6 files in S3 bucket, does that correspond to 6 PUT requests on S3 ? Or is the number of requests received by S3 via this UNLOAD query execution a higher number?

I would appreciate it if you could briefly clarify.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about **cost** then you're looking in the wrong place.

PUT requests in Amazon S3 (in a US region) are a **half-cent per 1000 requests**. Compare that to a Redshift cluster that is a minimum of 25c per hour (which is still rather good value).

Take a look at your monthly bill and S3 request pricing is unlikely to feature in your top costs.